# Displaying JSON data in a table from cURL using php

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to display JSON data in a table from cURL using php.

```
<?php

$lurl=get_fcontent("my_url");
function get_fcontent( $url) {
  $ch = curl_init(); //curl_init — Initialize a cURL session
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
  $content = curl_exec( $ch );
  $json = json_decode($content , true);
  echo $json;
}
?>
```

When I run that script in a browese it gives me json data, I want to pass that data to HTML table.

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following option to Curl to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

Also bear in mind that after you use `json_encode` you have an object not a json string so you can't print it out with `echo`. Instead you can use `print_r` or `var_dump`.